# При выборе опции selecta значение селекта не меняеется

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Всем привет!

Есть форма с бустраповским селектом. При загрузке страницы полю с селектом программно присваевается значение (id документа), например "13", вот так:

```
$('select.form-control[data-dif-property="property_fix2"]').val(doc_id);
```

Затем пользователь выбирает из селекта другую опцию, на экране все меняется на "3".
Когда пытаюсь получить значение с формы таким образом:

```
$('select.form-control[data-dif-property="property_fix2"]').val();
```

Получаю первоначальное значение  "13".

В чем может быть проблема? Буду признателен за любые наводки. Заранее спасибо.
Не привожу весь код, т.к. проект очень большой.

А вот такой код сгенерированной страницы в этом месте:

```
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control">
    <select text="" id="fi2" class="form-control" data-dif-select="" data-dif-datasource="selectF2" data-dif-property="property_fix2" data-live-search="true" placeholder="" tabindex="-98">
        <option id="0">1 </option>,
        <option id="1">2 </option>,
        <option id="2">3 </option>,
        <option id="3">4 </option>,
        <option id="4">5 </option>,
        <option id="5">6 </option>,
        <option id="6">7 </option>,
        <option id="7">8 </option>,
        <option id="8">9 </option>,
        <option id="9">10 </option>,
        <option id="10">11 </option>,
        <option id="11">12 </option>,
        <option id="12">13 </option>,
        <option id="13">14 </option>,
        <option id="14">15 </option>,
        <option id="15">16 </option>,
        <option id="16">17 </option>,
        <option id="17">18 </option>,
        <option id="18">19 </option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="fi2" title="3" aria-expanded="false">
        <div class="filter-option">
            <div class="filter-option-inner">
                <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">3</div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" role="combobox" x-placement="bottom-start" style="max-height: 606px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 46px; min-width: 160px; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);">
        <div class="bs-searchbox">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-label="Search">
        </div>
        <div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 542px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show">
                <li class="active selected">
                    <a role="option" class="dropdown-item active selected" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">
                        <span class="text">3 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">13 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как видно в коде присутствуют и 3 и 13.

Comment: Сам селект-то приведите

Comment: Всегда собирайте минимальный самодостаточной и воспроизводимым пример, чтобы Вам могли помочь. Предположим, у меня есть желание Вам помочь, но времени, понятное дело, у меня мало. Я смогу воспроизвести Вашу проблему из этой одной строчки кода? Нет, конечно. Даже если проблема тривиальна, пример все равно должен быть полным

Comment: Постарался добавить то, что смог.

Answer (score 0):

А где и как пытаетесь получить значение? Если делать это прямо внутри функции, которая будет вызываться при выборе опции - усё работает:

```js
let doc_id = 13;

let $select = $('select.form-control[data-dif-property="property_fix2"]');

$select.val(doc_id);

$select.on('change', function(){
  let val = $(this).val();
  console.clear(); console.log( val );
  $('.form-control').val( val );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select form-control">
  <select text="" id="fi2" class="form-control" data-dif-select="" data-dif-datasource="selectF2" data-dif-property="property_fix2" data-live-search="true" placeholder="" tabindex="-98">
    <option id="0">1 </option>,
    <option id="1">2 </option>,
    <option id="2">3 </option>,
    <option id="3">4 </option>,
    <option id="4">5 </option>,
    <option id="5">6 </option>,
    <option id="6">7 </option>,
    <option id="7">8 </option>,
    <option id="8">9 </option>,
    <option id="9">10 </option>,
    <option id="10">11 </option>,
    <option id="11">12 </option>,
    <option id="12">13 </option>,
    <option id="13">14 </option>,
    <option id="14">15 </option>,
    <option id="15">16 </option>,
    <option id="16">17 </option>,
    <option id="17">18 </option>,
    <option id="18">19 </option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-light" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="fi2" title="3" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="filter-option">
      <div class="filter-option-inner">
        <div class="filter-option-inner-inner">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" role="combobox" x-placement="bottom-start" style="max-height: 606px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 46px; min-width: 160px; position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 38px, 0px);">
    <div class="bs-searchbox">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-label="Search">
    </div>
    <div class="inner show" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" style="max-height: 542px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inner show">
        <li class="active selected">
          <a role="option" class="dropdown-item active selected" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="text">3 </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a role="option" class="dropdown-item" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="text">13 </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Значение получаю в отдельной функции, которая запускается по кнопке "Сохранить документ".